# Java compilation error when compiling dependent source files

Tags: java

So, I recently started class and objects in java and was solving the question:
Create a class named 'Student' with String variable 'name' and integer variable 'roll_no'. Assign the value of roll_no as '2' and that of name as "John" by creating an object of the class Student.

This is the code I wrote:

```
public class Student {
    
    String name;
    int roll_no;
}
```

I saved this in one file and

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Studentdemo {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new  Scanner(System.in);
        
        Student s = new Student();

        System.out.print("Enter the name: ");
        s.name = sc.next();

        System.out.print("Enter the roll number: ");
        s.roll_no = sc.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Name = " + s.name + "\nRoll No. = " + s.roll_no);
    }
}
```

I saved this in another file and tried to compile and run this code

```
error: cannot find symbol
        Student s = new Student();
        ^
  symbol:   class Student
  location: class Studendemo
ef.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        Student s = new Student();
                        ^
  symbol:   class Student
  location: class Studendemo
2 errors
error: compilation failed
```

I tried to run this code in an online compiler, it was running fine on that but not on ubunt

Comment: Are the classes in the same directory, did you compile them both? (first Student, then StudentDemo)? This is not an Ubuntu issue, it's likely you forgot to compile Student first

Comment: _tried to compile ... this code_ How did you try to compile? Did you enter the `javac` command in a terminal window? If yes, then [edit] your question and post the entire command, exactly as you entered it.

Comment: yes the classes are in the same directory, I compiled the first (Student) but it couldn't as there is no void main method in it, I even tried to use the 'extends' function as I made two new files with the same names as their classes and then I compiled StudentDemo as it included the main method and as it also had the class Student but  the error was not fixed as it still showed that " could not find symbol "